# I want to relocate to Switzerland, not to Otero, NM

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I try to add Switzerland to my relocation options on Careers. But Careers insist on relocating me to *Otero, NM. United States*. Switzerland is not accepted.

Steps to reproduce

1. Enter Switzerland into Relocation Option

   [image]
2. Move Cursor away from that field. Text changes to Otero

   [image]

And there is a related less obvious bug. It turns *Schweiz* (german for Switzerland) or *Swiss Confederation* (the official name of the country) into *Switzerland*. Which is great.  Unfortunately saving the changes replaces *Switzerland* with *Otero*. Probably because the entered values are sent to the location database again.

Steps to reproduc:

1. Add *Schweiz* into the same field.

   [image]
2. Move cursor away from that field

   [image]
3. Be happy, and save changes.
4. Look at profile overview. And see *Otero, NM.* at the end of the list.

Comment: Sure, it finds some remote region in New Mexico where there is a road named Zurich, but skips an entire country....well done. :)

Comment: Maybe Switzerland is full.

Comment: @J.Steen Looking out of the windows, I see they have started stacking people....you might have a point.

Comment: @J.Steen, I can confirm what Bart says, too many people here already :)

Comment: What's your problem with Otero, NM? ;)

Comment: Is it a coincidence that Otero County is, like, twenty miles from Area 51? I think not.

Comment: This is actually funny! Something funny on SO, yey!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please try again and let us know if the problem is fixed.

It looks like an invalid geolocation entry leaked into our database, we just cleaned it up manually.

Comment: Works. Thank you for the quick fix.